VSCODE Extensions showing installing
At my house I have a pc and a laptop. I am doing everything else smoothly. My current internet is very slow lately but not that slow either.
In both desktops my vscode is showing installing to all the extensions that I already have and if I want to download a new one then also shows installing. I am attaching a picture.

. All are stuck at installing.

try use another ide. you should install any jetbrains ide to check

what is the use to answer a VSC question with Jetbrain stuff

is this an answer or a comment?

Found a workaround by manually downloading from marketplace.
